# what does this bash script line of code mean

Tags: shell, awk, pipe

I am new to shell scripting and I found following line of code in a given script.

Could someone explain me with an example what the following line of code means

```
Path=`echo $line | awk -F '|' '{print $1}'`
```

Comment: This command prints the first chunk of a pipe separated string. `echo 'ciorgio|fjshs|dsjusj|hjdhs' | awk -F '|' '{print $1}'` prints 'ciorgio'

Answer (score 0):

`echo $line` will print the value of the variable `$line`, the `|` symbol means that the output of this will be passed (or [piped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix))) to another program/command/script. I will not attempt to explain [awk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) here, but what is done above is that the output from the `echo $line` is taken and processed with it.
the option `-FS` as per awk man page means

> -F fs Use fs for the input field separator

so the string after it will be used to split the input string given to awk into different fields. Example, you variable `$line` has a value of `a|b` it will be split into two fields `a` and `b`. What is to be done with this is specified within the `'{}'` expression. 
Again, what can be done in there is next to infinite, here the only thing that is done is to print the first field which can be accessed with `$1`, or `a` in the above example ($2 would be `b` as can be guessed).

Finally, the output of this whole operation is then stored in the variable `Path`.

to summarize:

```
line="a|b"
echo $line | awk -F '|' '{print $1}'
> a
Path=`echo $line | awk -F '|' '{print $1}'`
echo $Path
> a
```

Comment: awk is a program or interpreter for the awk programming language. You can invoke this program with various parameters to steer its behavior. I tried to explain the `-F` option in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $line | awk -F '|' '{print $1}'
```

Explanation:

```
echo -> display a line of text
$line -> parameter expansion read the line
| -> A  pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by one of the control operators |
awk -> Invoke awk program
-F '|' -> Field separator as | for the data feed
'{print $1}' -> Print the first field
```

Example

```
echo 'a|b|c' | awk -F '|' '{print $1}'
```

will print `a`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a complicated way to express

```
 echo ${line%%|*}
```

i.e. write to stdout the part of the content of the variable `line` which goes up to - but not including - the first vertical bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
Path=`echo $line | awk -F '|' '{print $1}'`
 ^           ^             ^           ^
 |           |             |           |
 |           |             |           print 1st column
 |           |             |
 |           |           input field separator
 |           |
 |          echo variable line
 | 
variable Path
```

- `-F'|'` - by default awk splits record/line/row into columns by single space, but with `|`, awk splits by pipe

Above one can be written as

```
Path=$( awk -F '|' '{ print $1 }' <<< "$line" )
```

Suppose say

```
$ line="1|2|3"
$ Path=$( awk -F '|' '{ print $1 }' <<< "$line" )
$ echo $Path; # you get first column
1
```

Same as

```
$ Path=$( cut -d'|' -f1 <<< "$line" )
$ echo $Path;
1
```

Answer (score -1):

the default field separator is  ' ', if you have -F , means change default separator to '|'